# When accessing an iframe with Selenium's "switchTo", "getPageSource" generates blank HTML

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a Java application that uses Selenium, and I am trying to access an iframe with "switchTo", but the return comes with the HTML body blank.

page1.html:

```
<html>
<head><head>
<doby>
<iframe id="iframe01" src="page2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html:

```
<html>
<head><head>
<doby>
<iframe id="iframe02" src="page3.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

My code:

```
String test0 = drive.getPageSource(); // This part goes through correctly.
WebElement element = drive.findElement(By.id("iframe1")); // Here is also okay.
drive.switchTo().frame(element);
String test1 = drive.getPageSource(); // Here it shows HTML without the body.
WebElement element = drive.findElement(By.id("iframe2")); // Here not found
```

In the "test1" variable, the return is:

```
<html>
<head><head>
<doby>
</body>
</html>
```

I have already tried using WebDriverWait and also tried using JavascriptExecutor, but I have not found any alternative regarding "switchTo".

The only way I found to solve this problem is by getting the "src" of "page1.html" and performing a new opening with "driver.get("")".

Comment: Where does the ID "iframePrincipal01" come from? Your posted HTML has "iframe01" and "iframe02". Have you tried `EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the example incorrectly. But I have already tried it.
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(element))`

I edited the mistake in the question.

Comment: Are you sure the two IFRAMEs are nested? `iframe02` is inside of `iframe01`? We can't help verify any of this without a link to the page.

Comment: "iframe1" has the "src" pointing to "page2". On "page2", I want to get the ID of the frame which would be "iframe2". The HTML is the same as in the example.

Comment: Does adding a wait or pausing the script help? Just wondering if the page inside the frame is loading slowly.

Comment: I've tried several methods, none of which were effective. Every time it goes through the switchTo command, it returns the HTML with the initial structure and nothing in the body.

I've tried using WebDriveWait with durations of 10, 30, and 50 seconds.
I also tried using ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated().
I also tried to see if it's some configuration issue with Firefox, but I haven't figured it out yet.